# Get the value of a select box

Tags: jquery

I have multiple dynamically set select boxes on my page (like over 100). I am trying to get the values of each box individually on change, but when the change takes place it iterates over every select box since they all have the same class. How can I get the values of each select box individually then do something...

**Example**

```
<select id="(dynamically set, may be different every time)" class="selection">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="dynamically set">1</option><option value="dynamically set">2</option>
  <option value="dynamically set">3</option>
</select>
<select id="(dynamically set, may be different every time)" class="selection">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="dynamically set">1</option>
  <option value="dynamically set">2</option>
  <option value="dynamically set">3</option></select>
<select id="(dynamically set, may be different every time)" class="selection">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="dynamically set">1</option>
  <option value="dynamically set">2</option>
  <option value="dynamically set">3</option></select>
etc...
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Psuedo code
$('.selection').change(function(){alert('test');});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.selection').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    //or
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: $(this).val() is much sexier than jQuery(this).val() :)

Comment: true, but it still iterates over all values, not the single one selected. The others show up as undefined

Comment: I just need to get the single box that was changed

Comment: @JuanGonzales That's what this code does. I.e. what `this` contains.

Comment: no, it gives me "this" of every box labeled .selection, not just the single changed select box

Comment: No it [does not](http://jsfiddle.net/JnTXw/).

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that... It is giving me the same value, just multiple times (seems to be the same amount of times as there are .selection fields)

Comment: It gives you the value of the select that changes. It does not iterate over all of them. If it is, you are doing something really wrong.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">$(".songSelect").change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
 });</script> is what i have

Comment: Nothing to do with the given code. You probably have something somewhere else which causes this. Now review your code and say: Sorry you were right :)

Comment: just set up a fiddle, I see what you mean.. not sure whats going on

Comment: dude, im such an IDIOT. I put the script inside a while loop. sorry, for wasting your time